# PL/SQL: Move data from Prod to Dev Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
Oracle 11g
Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.03
```

I need to copy all of the data from a production table with +100K rows to a development table.  The tables are in two different schemas.

I started to do:

```
select * 
  from prod_schema.prod_table 
 where ronum <= 50000 order by ID asc
```

Then do

```
select * 
  from prod_schema.prod_table 
 where ronum >= 50001 
   and rownum <=107161 order by ID asc
```

But the second query doesn't pull in any data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in batches? Why don't you just do them all in one go?

Answer (score 2):

ROWNUM in Oracle should never be compared as greater than (>).

When you query, Oracle numbers the rows AS THEY ARE RETURNED, so you cannot even say

```
where rownum > 1
```

because as rows are discarded, they get ignored. That is, in the above case there is never a ROWNUM=1 and you get no data at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query while using greater than with `ROWNUM` in oracle:

```
SELECT *
    FROM
     (SELECT a.*, rownum rn FROM
         (SELECT * FROM prod_schema.prod_table ORDER BY ID ASC) a WHERE rownum <= 107161)
    WHERE rn >= 50001;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html): `rownum` only gets assigned once a row enters the result set. So `where rownum > 1` will never return any row.

Do that in a single select (`insert into / select * from` possibly with an `/*+ append */` hint, or use CTAS). Or use `expdp`/`impdp`: you can use the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option with that to change the schema name (and possibly restrict the selected set depending you your version of Oracle).